# Find element by ID on page - then execute function | JavaScipt

Tags: javascript

I have multiple functions in my Chrome extention, that for the time being are assigned to individual buttons (4 in total). I would like to cut this is half, down to 2 buttons.

All functions use `getElementByID` to locate a text input field, and automatically place a generated value in this field.

There are only minor variations in the functions.

The full function looks like this:

```
function code_no_email() {
    const generateRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    };
    var VerCodeNO = generateRandomNumber(111111, 999999);
    var VerCodeTextNO = "Verifiseringskode: ";
    var VerCodeCompleteNO = VerCodeTextNO + VerCodeNO;
    //Auto-paste to email text fields
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, (tabs) => {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {
                tabId: tabs[0].id
            },
            args: [VerCodeCompleteNO],
            func: (VerCodeCompleteNO) => {
                document.getElementById("subject").value = VerCodeCompleteNO;
                document.getElementById("text").value = VerCodeCompleteNO;
            },
        });
    });
}
```

If I add a third and final line to this `document.getElementById("Message").value = VerCodeCompleteNO;` at the end, it will not fill in the value in the "Message" field, to my understanding because it fails when the other two are not found.

To my understanding the following should eliminate this issue.

```
function VerCodeNOShort(){
if(document.getElementById("subject") != false){
    code_no_email();
} else if(document.getElementById("Message") != false) {
    code_no_sms();
}else{
    console.log("fizzbuzz");
}
}
```

Agian, it is not able to fill in on the page that contains the field with Id "Message", only the one with "subject".

Using `!= null` only returned errors.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `getElementById` returns null if no element was found with the given ID, isn't that what you want ?

Comment: Please note that a single `=` means assignment

Answer (score 1):

Just check if it's null.

```
if(document.getElementById("abc") != null){
    fizz();
} else if(document.getElementById("xyz") != null) {
    buzz();
}else{
    console.log("fizzbuzz");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, while this helped, it did not solve my issue. Using `!= false` instead got me a bit further. Did a rewrite of the question to hopefully clarify my question.